# Изменение размеров SVG с помощью <input type="range"> не работает в FireFox

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer, input, firefox

Всем привет.
Делаю ползунок для изменения размера SVG.
Не работает в IE11 и FireFox. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить код?

```js
function sizePic() {
 var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
 var img = document.querySelector('svg');
 img.style.width = size;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      <input type="range" min="50" max="760" id="size" onchange="sizePic()" value="760">
      <div>
        <svg width="200" height="200" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
           <g>
           <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

           </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас какая-то совершенно адовая смесь из стилей и атрибутов в самом SVG, потому я чуть-чуть его подчистил.

Если ширину менять не через `style.width`, а через `setAttribute('width', width)`, то всё работает. Проверено в последнем Фаерфоксе.

```js
window.onload = sizePic;

document.getElementById("size").addEventListener('input', sizePic);

function sizePic() {
 var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
 var img = document.querySelector('svg');
 img.setAttribute('width', size)
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      <input type="range" min="50" max="760" id="size" value="760">
      <div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
           <g>
           <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

           </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как раз не зря добавил эту адовую смесь из стилей, т.к. в моем варианте она присутствует в SVG, потому что он создается динамически скриптом и изменить эти стили возможности нет. По этому такой вариант не подходит, в нем поле картинки расширяется, а сама остается на месте. И в IE11 не работает